Why doesn't a byte slice satisfy a generic type constraint of an any slice?
I have the following code with two generic functions. They both do the simple operation of appending a slice to itself and returning the result. However, invoking the simpler and more straightforward function cat1 produces a compilation error while invoking the more clumsily defined function cat2 with its superfluous and explicit declaration of the slice element E works as expected. Why isn't cat1 acceptable?
func cat1[S ~[]any](s S) S {
  return append(s, s...)
}

func cat2[S ~[]E, E any](s S) S {
  return append(s, s...)
}

func main() {
  fmt.Println(string(cat2([]byte("hello"))))
}

The error when invoking cat1 is:
[]byte does not satisfy ~[]any ([]byte missing in ~[]any)

https://go.dev/play/p/IJzCEiPglgA

~[]any as a constraint means any data type derived from a slice of any. The longer constraint means that you should have a type derived from slice of E where E can be anything.

Also, slices are not covariant: byte is a subtype of any, but []byte is not a subtype of []any.

So, I need to include the E any type parameter even though I never declare, use or return any variables of type E in this function?  I'll accept that as the answer even though it seems the compiler should understand that []byte satisfies []any just as byte satisfies any. Seems pedantic.

[]byte does not satisfy []any, because they are distinct types with different underlying memory layouts. []any is not an interface, it is a slice of empty interface values.

Type constraints must be interfaces, however the keyword interface is almost always omitted as a syntactic sugar.
Therefore when you use ~[]any as a type constraint, what you're actually writing is:
interface{ ~[]any }

In this interface, ~[]any is a type term. What types can satisfy this constraint? As with all constraints:

A type argument T satisfies a type constraint C if T is an element of the type set defined by C

The type set defined by your constraint C a.k.a. interface{ ~[]any } is the type literal []any and all types with []any as underlying type. For example:
type Foo []any

[]byte is not included in the type set of interface{ ~[]any }, just like outside of generic code you couldn't assign a []byte to an []any:
var a []byte
var b []any
b = a // compilation error

As @JimB mentioned in a comment, byte and any have different memory layouts, therefore their composite types aren't mutually assignable.
Now when you use any alone as a type constraint, things change. any is an alias of interface{} (the empty interface). In this case there is no syntactic sugar. The constraint is just interface{} which is an interface with no methods and no type terms. All types implement it, including byte.
Your second function cat2 is the only correct way to define a type parameter S that can be any slice:
func cat2[S ~[]E, E any](s S) S {
  return append(s, s...)
}

Here E is constrained to any type, and S resolves to a slice of whatever E is.
